# Lets Encrypt 403 Error When Installing Certificate

Tags: urllib2, bitnami, lets-encrypt, http-error, certbot

I receive a `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error when attempting to install a Lets Encrypt certificate using Certbot. I have been installing certificates using the steps listed in [this](https://docs.bitnami.com/godaddy/components/apache/#how-to-generate-and-install-a-lets-encrypt-certificate-for-your-domain-using-the-certbot-client) article for over a year and recently starting running into an issue on many of my servers.

**The environment of each of the servers with the issue:**
GoDaddy Cloud Server (512MB)
Bitnami Wordpress
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Python 2.7.6

**Here are the outputs when attempting to install a certificate:**

```
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ -d xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
Bootstrapping dependencies for Debian-based OSes... (you can skip this with --no-bootstrap)
Ign http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg  
Get:2 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [399 kB]
28% [2 Sources 63.9 kB/399 kB 16%] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Get:3 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6,331 B]
Get:4 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [180 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Get:5 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,764 B]
Get:6 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [984 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Get:7 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Get:8 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [408 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Get:9 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.3 kB]
Get:10 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [941 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:11 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16.9 kB]
Get:12 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [408 kB]
Get:13 http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.6 kB]
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://iad-public-cmh-zone-1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 3,463 kB in 8s (395 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
augeas-lenses is already the newest version.
ca-certificates is already the newest version.
libaugeas0 is already the newest version.
libffi-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
python-virtualenv is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
WARNING: unable to check for updates.
Creating virtual environment...
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Installing Python packages...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.rG5cNt1Qm0/pipstrap.py", line 146, in <module>
    exit(main())
  File "/tmp/tmp.rG5cNt1Qm0/pipstrap.py", line 130, in main
    for url, digest in PACKAGES]
  File "/tmp/tmp.rG5cNt1Qm0/pipstrap.py", line 112, in hashed_download
    response = opener().open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

**UPDATE**

Here is what happens when I try to download the tar files from `pypi.python.org`

```
bitnami@atv-demo:/tmp$ sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-8.0.3.tar.gz
--2017-06-07 06:58:33--  https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-8.0.3.tar.gz
Resolving pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)... 151.101.32.223, 2a04:4e42:8::223
Connecting to pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)|151.101.32.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-06-07 06:58:33 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

bitnami@atv-demo:/tmp$ sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-20.2.2.tar.gz
--2017-06-07 06:58:41--  https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-20.2.2.tar.gz
Resolving pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)... 151.101.32.223, 2a04:4e42:8::223
Connecting to pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)|151.101.32.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-06-07 06:58:41 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

bitnami@atv-demo:/tmp$ sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/wheel/wheel-0.29.0.tar.gz
--2017-06-07 06:58:48--  https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/wheel/wheel-0.29.0.tar.gz
Resolving pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)... 151.101.32.223, 2a04:4e42:8::223
Connecting to pypi.python.org (pypi.python.org)|151.101.32.223|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-06-07 06:58:48 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

According to the traceback you shared, the error occurred while trying to download a Python package. The list of URLs that the script tries to download is:

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-8.0.3.tar.gz
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-20.2.2.tar.gz
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/wheel/wheel-0.29.0.tar.gz
```

And optionally:

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/argparse/argparse-1.4.0.tar.gz
```

Taking into account the URLs point to `pypi.python.org`, this was probably a transient error.

Alternatively, you may try to install Certbot from the [official PPA](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-apache) instead of using `certbot-auto`.

Comment: I've updated the question to show what happens when I try to download the packages manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've run the same commands as you and every link worked. Are you using a proxy? You could also try to download the packages with `curl`, adding `-v` to get verbose output and check if it provides any additional clues.

Comment: Not currently using a proxy, but it looks like I might need to. I attempted to download using curl and received the following error: `The requestors Network has been blacklisted due to excessive request volume. If you are a hosting customer, please contact your hosting company's support. If you are the hosting company, please contact infrastructure-staff@python.org to resolve.`. I'm using a GoDaddy Cloud Server. I assume this means that unlucky GoDaddy servers have been blacklisted and that is why I have numerous servers with this issue.

Comment: Yes, if your network has been blacklisted then you won't be able to download the packages from inside that network. You may try to install Certbot using the official PPA instead, which will download the package from a different repo.